# In DITA-OT ibmUtilitiesDomain.ent

Tags: html, dita, dita-ot

On running the DITA conversion on DITA-OT we are getting the following error,

"The XML parser reported the following error: : D:\DITA-OT1.8.4_full_easy_install_bin\DITA-OT1.8.4\dtd\utilities\ibmUtilitiesDomain.ent (The system cannot find the path specified)"

Where can I get ibmUtilitiesDomain.ent file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`ibmUtilitiesDomain.ent` is part of IBM specific Author Information DTD that is not bundled with DITA-OT. You need to find the DTD module somewhere and save it locally somewhere DITA-OT can access it.

Comment: Do you have a DTD module that contains the ibmUtilitiesDomain.ent and the mod file?